# JDO update operation on a list not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdo

I'm trying to update the roles of users available using the below method

```
    PersistenceManager pm = connectionFactory.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class, "email == '" + email + "'");
        List<User> user = (List<User>) query.execute();
        user.get(0).getRoles().clear();
        for (Role r : roles) {
            user.get(0).getRoles().add(pm.getObjectById(Role.class, r.getId()));
        }
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
        pm.close();
    }
```

What I observed is that, not all roles are getting assigned. It's inconsistent and sometimes 3 out of 5 roles get assigned, sometimes all of them, sometimes non of them.

According to the documentation what I understood is,

1. An existing PersistenceManager instance is required to update the object.
2. pm.makePersistent() is not required if the object is already persisted to update it.
3. To update the object tx.begin() and tx.commit() are required.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using MySQL as the database.

---Edit---

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "USER_INFO")
public class User{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long Id;
    @Persistent
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Persistent
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Persistent
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Persistent
    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phonenumber;
    @Column(name = "VALID")
    private Boolean isValidUser = true;
    @Persistent
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private String active;

    @Persistent(table = "USER_ROLE_RELATION", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Join(column = "USER_ID")
    @Element(column = "ROLE_ID")
    private List<Role> role = new ArrayList<Role>();

    @Persistent(table = "USER_STREAM_RELATION", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Join(column = "USER_ID")
    @Element(column = "STREAM_ID")
    private List<Stream> stream = new ArrayList<Stream>();

}

@PersistenceCapable(table = "ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2600988373295393375L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, column = "ROLE_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Unique
    @Persistent(column = "ROLE_NAME")
    private String roleName;
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<UserInfo> user;
}
```

I'm trying to update the roles. That is remove previously added roles and add new roles

Exception thrown:

```
  2017-01-25 15:09:11 DEBUG Datastore:58 - Using PreparedStatement "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@6e68bf64"
2017-01-25 15:09:11 DEBUG Native:58 - INSERT INTO `USER_ROLE_RELATION` (`ROLE_ID`,`USER_ID`,`IDX`) VALUES (<3>,<1>,<1>) 
  2017-01-25 15:09:11 DEBUG NewPooledConnection:430 - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7d7d54ba handling a throwable.
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)

2017-01-25 15:09:11 DEBUG DefaultConnectionTester:126 - Testing a Connection in response to an Exception:
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
```

Comment: how can anyone comment on that without showing the persistable classes, and the log showing what actually happens? The log tells you lifecycle states, so you can DEBUG what happens with each line of your code. You can also mention what you are trying to achieve by that ... add a Role that already exists in the "roles" field?

Comment: Look at the log as already said. Debug what happens with each addition to the list, including what "lifecycle state" objects are in. Nobody here can see that, but you can. PS the vast majority of your annotations are utterly pointless.

Comment: You are right! Some of these annotations were pointless. I have now fixed the issue. Thanks for the push!